Incorrect emails content with only a boundary identifier is sent
With use of AWS SES, I have an issue that some users sometime receive our emails with strange content like below:

The content starts with "------=_Part" is known as a boundary identifier. I have no idea for this issue and I find no solution for this.
I have checked:

the response code from client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest); is 200 and valid messageId
domain record is set properly (dmarc is aligned)
AWS SES dashboard shows no Rejects/Complaints
Just 0.5% sending quote used

Here is the java code to send an email:
   private Boolean sendOneEmail(SesClient client,
                                                String sender,
                                                String recipient,
                                                String subject,
                                                String bodyText,
                                                String bodyHTML
) throws Exception {

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Add subject, from and to lines.
    message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));

    // Create a alternative child container.
    MimeMultipart msgBody = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    // Create a wrapper for the HTML and text parts.
    MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Define the text part.
    MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    // Define the HTML part.
    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent(bodyHTML, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    // Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msgBody.addBodyPart(textPart);
    msgBody.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

    // Add the child container to the wrapper object.
    wrap.setContent(msgBody);

    // Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
    MimeMultipart msg = new MimeMultipart("multipart");

    // Add the parent container to the message.
    message.setContent(msg);

    // Add the multipart/alternative part to the message.
    msg.addBodyPart(wrap);

    try {
        log.info("Send an email through Amazon SES: " + sender);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(outputStream);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray());

        byte[] arr = new byte[buf.remaining()];
        buf.get(arr);

        SdkBytes data = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(arr);
        RawMessage rawMessage = RawMessage.builder()
                                    .data(data)
                                    .build();

        AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration myConf = AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                                                     .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                                                     .build();

        SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = SendRawEmailRequest.builder()
                                                  .rawMessage(rawMessage)
                                                  .overrideConfiguration(myConf)
                                                  .build();

        SendRawEmailResponse response = client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
        int responseCode = response.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode();
        String messageId = response.messageId();
        log.info("Email message Sent. sender={}, recipient={}, subject={}, response={} responseCode={} messageId={}",
          sender, recipient, subject, response, responseCode, messageId);
        if (responseCode != 200) {
            log.debug("responseCode={} messageId={} metadata={} sdkHttpResponse={}",
              responseCode, messageId, response.responseMetadata().toString(), response.sdkHttpResponse().toString());
        }
        return responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 300 && !StringUtils.isEmpty(messageId);
    } catch (SesException|IOException e) {
        log.error("sendOneEmail error, sender={}, recipient={}, subject={}, bodyText={}, bodyHTML={}",
            sender, recipient, subject, bodyText, bodyHTML, e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }


Update: It is given that the mail can be read from other mail clients. The issue only appears in Apple Mail.
